# How should one access windows files with WSL in VSCode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sqlite3-ruby

The problem I'm having is related to starting heroku up with the WSL Bash console built into VSCode.

Basically, it's my understanding that WSL maps your windows files with a slightly different path (using /mnt/drive/file), but why is it that these files are not the same as the files on my windows hard drive, and is there any way to directly access windows files?

Why is my Ruby version different in WSL?

I had thought this was because I'm running a virtual machine that doesn't have the same files at all, but I'm reading that my actual windows files should be mapped into WSL.  Is it because they're only mapped once, at the time in which WSL in set up?  Either way, I'm having problems accessing files, and have been searching for hours to no avail, and I'm thinking about ditching WSL completely.  The only problem is that it seems to have some advantages.

I'm having problems loading sqlite3 in windows using powershell, but for some reason it loads just fine with WSL.  The error I get with powershell is "Cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)".  I've tried pretty much every solution in every thread I've looked at and nothing has worked.

Solutions tried -

```
"gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
bundle install

gem uninstall sqlite3 --all
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
gem inst sqlite3 --platform ruby
```

- Reinstalling sqlite3
- Different versions of sqlite3
- Different ranges of versions.

Once again, I would use WSL, but the file system appears to be different than my local Windows 10 files.  I only need to fix *one* of these problems in order to be able to run my heroku procfile.  Ideally I'd fix the fact that heroku isn't accessible from my file system but this remains the slightly more mysterious problem.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it that these files are not the same as the files on my windows hard drive, and is there any way to directly access windows files?

They are the same.
WSL filesystem is not accessible from Windows. But you can access Windows filesystem in WSL - it's mounted as an external storage at `/mnt/<letter of your volume>/dirs/file`.

> Why is my Ruby version different in WSL?

If you installed Ruby on Windows you and it is in your Windows PATH, you can access it via `ruby.exe` in WSL. Windows `PATH` variable is being loaded into WSL. But you can't run WSL programs in Windows. BUT I DON'T recommend it. I think it won't run files located in WSL filesystem.

> I'm having problems loading sqlite3 in windows using powershell, but for some reason it loads just fine with WSL.

Install sqlite for Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if they are the same, why can't I see heroku in mnt/a/Program Files with WSL?  I can see it just fine in Windows.

My sqlite3 command came back with "SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53" so I had installed it, but it still does not work with regular powershell.  The error I'm getting is "Cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)"